# jQuery: set json as dataType when using .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

```
$(...).load('index.html', params)
```

Is there a way to instruct `load` to pass params as JSON?

Does `$.ajaxSetup({})` affect the load function?

---

**Example object I want to send:**

```
{ 'state'  : [ { 'city' : 'city-foo' , 'zip'  : 'zip-foo' },
               { 'city' : 'city-bar' , 'zip'  : 'zip-bar' }
             ],
  'person' : [ { 'name' : 'name-foo' },
               { 'name' : 'name-bar' }
             ]
}
```

**What it's coming in as (unwanted, indvidual params):**

```
state[0][city]
state[0][zip]
state[1][city]
state[1][zip]
person[0][name]
person[1][name]
```

**What I'm expecting/wanting:**

param name is something like *json* with that has a value:`"{'state':[{'city':'city-foo','zip':'zip-foo'},{'city':'city-bar','zip':'zip-bar'}],'person':[{'name':'name-foo'},{'name':'name-bar'}]}"`

---

#### Further Information

I'm trying to use this with bootstrap.js and select2.js - specifically passing the multiselect values to a script and returning values to a modal.

```
var param = {/* object similar in structure to above example */};
$('#modal-id').load('?do=givemevalues', param ).modal('show')
```

Here's an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/Kv5uY/), which you can explore with firebug to see how params are past in the POST.

Comment: You can pass parameters using GET or POST. How/why would you want to use JSON inside of that?

Comment: I hope you will forgive me, but I'm confused as to why you would want to handle JSON data in a jQuery load callback.  That function is built specifically for replacing bits of HTML.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @BuckWild: passing the values as a JSON object so that my script (PHP, Perl, etc) can take that value and parse it into a native object.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I'm testing out the jQuery select2 plugin for Bootstrap and the multi-select does not use a native form element interface.  I could format as standard key/value pairs, but I was curious if it might format the params into something more JSON friendly, since my value might be a nested object (eg `{ statename : { city : cityname , bird : statebird , timezone : current-tz } }`)

Comment: @vol7ron: Ah, I misread and thought you were talking about the response.  I think Vega is correct, the data parameter can be a JavaScript PlainObject according to the documentation.

Comment: @BuckWild: I tried that and have posted more info as to what's happening and something more along the lines of what I guess I was  expecting

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a way to instruct load to pass params as JSON?**

The param can be string or an object.. which by itself satisfies JSON notation. However it is upto the server to parse that as JSON.

Also note that the `Request Method` changes based on the param type.

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

**Does $.ajaxSetup({}) affect the load function?**

Yes it does, below is from the documentation.

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

Comment: So what I notice is that passing it as an object made the params come in as something like `state[0][key1] state[0][key2] state[1][key1] state[1][key2]`, which I don't know too much about valid JSON, but I was expecting something more like `{state:[{key1:value1,key2:value2}, {key1:value1,key2:value2}]}`

Comment: @vol7ron Not sure how you are passing the param. Can you post the value of param object that is getting passed?

Comment: yes, I appreciate the help btw.  How would you like me to post it.  I tried to update the answer as to what's happening.  Perhaps a fiddle might help if I can construct one quickly.

Comment: @vol7ron I think you need to check your server side to make sure that it is getting parsed correctly. From what I see, your server doesn't recognize the param as JSON and so it constructs individual strings.

Comment: wouldn't the construction come from the client?  I attached a fiddle to the end of the question (above), but you need to browse what is happening in Firebug

Comment: notice how if you use `JSON.stringify(param)`, it sends it as a JSON string